# Point on a line segment

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a line segment defined by two end points. And I have another randomly chosen third point and I want to find out if the third point is on the line segment or not. By "On the line segment", I mean that exactly on the line segment, not intersecting the line segment and end up on the other side of the line segment. I hope I explained the issue. Some mathematical explanation along with reasonings/reference to the reasonings are eagerly requested.

Thanks

Comment: What is the context? Vectors, computing...

Comment: If vectors, any point on the line between a and b is of the form r = a+t(b - a) where t is a real number. A point between a and b has 0<t<1. Substitute your point for r and calculate t. If you have several dimensions, calculate t for each dimension. They should be consistent (same value of t = point is on line) and 0<t<1.

Comment: Hi @Paul , what do you mean by context here ? I want have a function in programming  that detects if a point is on a line  segment or not

Comment: By context I mean that the answers given here do not refer to programming - maybe you know the vector stuff but want code?.

Answer (score 0):

Let the endpoints of your segment be $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$;  we want to figure out whether a point $(x,y)$ lies on the segment connecting these two points.  This point $(x,y)$ will lie on the line segment if and only if all three of the conditions below are true:

- $x \in [x_1, x_2]$ (or $x \in [x_2, x_1]$ if $x_2 < x_1$.)  This basically states that if the $x$-coordinate of the point is outside the range of $x$-coordinates spanned by the line segment, there is no chance that it lies on the line segment.
- $y \in [y_1, y_2]$ (or $y \in [y_2, y_1]$ if $y_2 < y_1$.)  This is the same condition for the $y$-coordinate.
- $(x_2 - x_1)(y - y_1) = (x - x_1)(y_2 - y_1)$.  This equation may look a little strange, but if $x_2 \neq x_1$ it can be rearranged to read
  $$
  \frac{y - y_1}{x - x_1} = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1},
  $$
  which says that the slope of the line connecting $(x,y)$ to $(x_1, y_1)$ is the same as the slope of the line connecting $(x_2,y_2)$ to $(x_1, y_1)$.  The first form of the equation above also covers the case where $x_2 = x_1 = x$.

This assumes that everything is in 2-D.  The first two conditions generalize pretty straightforwardly to higher dimensions, while the last one is best written as
$$
\frac{x - x_1}{x_2 - x_1} = \frac{y - y_1}{y_2 - y_1} = \frac{z - z_1}{z_2 - z_1} = \dots
$$
When written in this form, you can simply ignore the conditions that lead to quantities of the form $0/0$ (i.e., when the endpoints have one or equal coordinates);  only the quantities that are well-defined need to be equal.

Answer (score 0):

So you've got a line $g$ with points $A$ and $B$ which define linesegment $|AB|$. You want to know if another point, let's say $C$, is part of the linesegment $|AB|$.

**step 1: is $C \in g$?**

Write line $g$ in its parametric form
$$\begin{bmatrix}  x\\y\\z\\\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}  x_A\\y_A\\z_A\\\end{bmatrix}\times t \begin{bmatrix}  x_B-x_A \\y_B-y_A\\z_B-z_A\\\end{bmatrix}$$

find $t$ for $x=x_C$:
$$t=\frac{x_C-x_A}{x_b-x_A}$$

Use this $t$ to calculate $y$ and $z$, if your point $C \in g$ your calculated $y,z = y_C,z_C$

**step 2: is $C \in |AB|$?**

Determine vector $\vec{AC}$ and $\vec{BC}$,

if $\vec{AC} \bullet \vec{BC} <0, C \in |AB|$

if $\vec{AC} \bullet \vec{BC} >0, C \notin |AB|$